# Передача ip-адреса без формы

Tags: python, django

Есть простенькая страничка на Django, где есть форма с двумя полями (Имя, Номер), как мне при сабмите передавать в БД еще и ip-адрес клиента?

Небольшой апдейт, делал вот таким образом

```
<div> 
    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %} 
        {{ form }} 
        <input type="hidden" name="ip" value="{{ ip }}"> 
        <div> 
            <button type="submit">Отправить</button> 
        </div> 
    </form> 
    </div>
```

при принте POST запроса, ip туда попадает В админке его нет :C

Comment: Используйте кнопку [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/872088/edit) для редактирования вопроса.

Comment: так на коммит формы добавь ip)

Comment: @МихаилВасильченко добавте свой апдейт в вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Судя, по `{{ form }}`, у вас используются django-формы, а видимо есть какая-то модель, куда данные из формы сохраняются.

Так вот **нужно проверить**, чтобы поле `ip` было и в модели, и в классе формы.

Тогда это поле будет правильно отрисовываться на странице, и сохраняться в базу.

**Альтернативный вариант:**

Во view, куда прилетает форма по submit, нужно получать данные поля `ip` через `request.POST.get('ip')` и сохранять в бд.

Comment: В моделях все три поля есть, в классе формы ip, находится в Exclude, насколько я понял, это означает, что это поле не будет отрисовываться, про альтернативный вариант можно подробней?

Comment: Да, нужно использовать альтернативный вариант.